# Exportar tabela Postgre SQL para texto (csv) via psycopg2

Tags: sql, python, postgresql

estou tentando exportar uma tabela da base Postgres para um arquivo txt (csv) via Python, através do psycopg2. Porém, estou encontrando um erro. O código é o seguinte (troquei as informações de login para postar):

```
import psycopg2

# Definição da conexão com a DB onde informo o nome, o usuário, a senha e o IP.
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=dbname user=user password=password host=iphost")

# Abertura da conexão para execução de queryes.
cur = conn.cursor()

# Query de consulta da tabela empresa. columns=None

f = open("\\\\server\\arquivos\\BD\\log.txt", "w")
copy_to(f, 'wphd.empresa', sep=';', null='')
f.close()

# Fechar conexão com a DB.
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

O erro que retorna é o seguinte:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Py\Db\Conn_B_working.py", line 12, in <module>
    copy_to(f, 'wphd.empresa', sep=';', null='')
NameError: name 'copy_to' is not defined
```

Alguem saberia me dizer o que está faltando?
Grato!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como pode-se ver na [documentação](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_to), `copy_to` é um método da classe  `cursor`:

```
cur.copy_to(f, 'wphd.empresa', sep=';', null='')
```

Comment: Rápido e certeiro. Muito obrigado e desculpa pela vergonha de iniciante. Funcionou!